# Get real height of div plus css generated content (if possible)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use javascript to give three ULs nested inside divs a negative top position equal to their height. I've got it working, sort of (thanks to help from here!) but instead of calculating the height of each nested UL and calculating the top position accordingly, each UL is being assigned a negative top position of -367px:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Get height of footer popup
    var pHeight = $('footer ul li > ul').outerHeight(); 
    //Calculate new top position based on footer popup height
    var nHeight = pHeight + "px";         
    $('footer ul li > ul').css({ 
        //Change top position to equal height of footer popup
        'top' : "-" + nHeight    
    });
});
</script>
```

I've tried this using `.height`, `.outerheight`, and even `.getheight` which someone mentioned on the Jquery documentation for `.height`. I also tried using an each statement, though it didn't seem to work; I may have written it incorrectly.

In addition (if possible), I'd like the negative position to take into account the height of a content being generated using the css `:after` psuedo-property, though I can always manually add that in to the calculation if javascript has no way to access that.

**EDIT:** Added a test page link. It's the bottom divs (and nested ULs) I'm trying to target with JS; the "tails" on each box should line up at about 1.2em above their parent divs.

http://www.qualityprinters2.com/test/float-tab-test.html

Comment: I don't see any "DIVs" in your code...can you setup a test page and attach a screenshots of the current work and how it should look like?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the each() jquery function (see http://api.jquery.com/each/).  When your selector 'footer ul li > ul' returns more than one element, it is only computing the height of the first matched element.

Comment: I'd tried it without much luck: 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


$('footer ul li > ul').each(function(){


var pHeight = $(this).outerHeight(); //Get height of footer popup

var nHeight = pHeight + "px"; //Calculate new top position based on footer popup height

    
  $(this).css({ //Change top position to equal height of footer popup

   'top' : "-" + nHeight


 });


});

</script>

I think it's just because I have trouble understanding how they're written. I've stared at the documentation till my eyes crossed but I'm still confused.

Comment: At quick glance, this looks correct.  Is your position relative?  Have you tried alert(nHeight) to make sure the value you're expecting is coming through?

Comment: I toyed with it for a while and came up with this, which does iterate through the divs and compute their height/adjust the top margin accordingly:
$('footer ul li > ul').each(function(i) {
var pHeight = $(this).outerHeight(); 
var diff = Math.abs(330 - pHeight); 
var nHeight = diff + 460 + "px"; 
  $(this).css({ 
   'top' : "-" + nHeight

 });
 });
});

But because the divs are different sizes, their bottoms are still not lining up. Some are way above their parent and others are far below it. I'm stumped, which sucks, because I need to finish this by tomorrow. Oh, they're position:absolute.

Comment: I set up a test page in my original question so you can see what's going on.

Comment: I would narrow your test page (and sample code) down to exactly what you're focusing on, so myself and others can figure out what it is you're trying to do.  I see you keep mentioning DIVs, however your selector is selecting UL elements.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant UL. There are divs inside the ULs, which is what I was thinking of, but it's the ULs I'm trying to target.